# Line Gap in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, layout

I want to add gaps between ASP.NET Controls, At the moment only way I know is by adding `<br />` but the gap I want should be less then two line breaks but more then 1 line break, not sure how I can do it in ASP.NET.

**EDIT**

I would like to know best practice please

Comment: Add a div and set its style height property.

Comment: CSS can be used for your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about

```
<asp:TextBox ID="ctrl1" />
<div style="height: 10px;">&nbsp</div>
<asp:TextBox ID="ctrl2" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a class to your ASP.NET controls and control its 'margin-bottom' property in your css file

```
.yourClass
{
margin-bottom: 12px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the controls in `<div class="mySpacedControlContainer"> ... </div>` tags.

Add CSS somewhere - dedicated CSS file, inline CSS - containing

```
.mySpacedControlContainer { margin-bottom: 1em; }
```

Adjust the value to taste.

You could also apply the CSS class directly to the controls.

Answer (score 0):

What about using DIV with padding?

```
<div id="div1">
Div One
</div>

<div id="div2">
Div Two
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#div1 {
border: 1px dashed red;
padding: 20px;
margin: 40px;
}

#div2 {
border: 1px dashed green;
padding: 5px;
margin: 10px;
}
```